# Is SkyScanner's 3D earth interface for flights to "everywhere" only on their smartphone app?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, flight-search-engines

Yesterday a friend who's no longer around showed me how you could look for tickets on [SkyScanner](http://www.skyscanner.net) from a given city or airport to "everywhere" with [a 3D globe interface](http://kotikan.com/ourwork/skyscanner/screen1.png).

It had tags on various destinations with showing the cheapest prices and you could rotate around revealings the various parts of the world to find bargains. Great for when you want to go somewhere without a fixed plan but on a low budget!

But I can't seem to find the feature on the PC version - my friend was using a smartphone. **Does anyone know if this 3D earth interface is available from their web page? How do I find it?**

Comment: Sadly, this seems to be a feature only on their iOS application, which the Android version is lacking.

Comment: <sup>`)-:`</sup>

Comment: there is something similar, the skyscanner [maps API](http://api.skyscanner.net/api/ajax/maps/introduction.html). ([here](http://www.skyscanner.nl/cheap-flights-map) on their site as functionality). It's not 3D, and not as dynamic and interactive as the mobile application, but shows low prices on mouseover.

Comment: @Joris: Yes I'd found (the English version of) that page when I was hunting for the 3D globe. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there's no 3D option, one trick you can do to get a list:

- Go to [Skyscanner's website](http://www.skyscanner.net/).
- Enter the dates you want to travel.
- Enter the city you're travelling FROM, but leave the destination BLANK.
- Hit search.

It'll then provide you with a list of all the countries you could travel to, in order of price.

I used to do this regularly to find cheap flights for weekend trips from London.

Skyscanner does have a map, just not "3d" - more like "2.5d", so for example, to [show flights from Canada](http://www.skyscanner.net/cheap-flights-map).

If you want another map, however, I suggest [Kayak's Explore feature](http://www.kayak.com/explore/), which allows faceted search of destinations from your location, on a map of the world.