# Is there an app for Android to look for flights with a "go anywhere" option search?

Tags: online-resources, flight-search-engines, mobile-apps

I thought if you wanted to search for fare prices from one city for a specific date to anywhere under a specific price Momondo, Google Flights or Skyscanner are the stuff to use but they don't work on my Android phone. Are there any apps to have this search option for Android?

Comment: Would this not be a good support question for Momondo? Often apps are reduced functionality versions of their websites..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this about the specific functionality within an app. For an alternative site, I can get this migrated to [Webapps StackExchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) - just leave me a comment!

Comment: Sorry going to edit when I get a moment. Actually I want to know which travel app I can use for a "go anywhere" search function on my phone! I see tons of app question on travel.

Comment: Example:http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9240/is-skyscanners-3d-earth-interface-for-flights-to-everywhere-only-on-their-sma?rq=1

Comment: You can try the skyscanner application.

Comment: If SkyScanner does not work for you as an app, their website is fully optimized for mobile browsers, there is no need for the app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a standalone app for this.

You can use [Adioso](http://adioso.com/) for open ended searches and it has a responsive design that will work on your device. The only part that it won't do is restrict the search to be under a certain price.

You can add the site as a bookmark to your home screen and it will not really be much different to what a standalone app could offer.

Comment: Price restricting is the most important feature. ☺

Comment: You could use their "Watch prices" option to get deals sent to you by email. That includes a price filter.

Comment: Definitely trying it now! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use wander for that, it's a travel destination search engine, you enter budget & dates, and you receive destinations that fits within that...

[Wander - travel destination search](http://www.wanderapp.me)